# Sed/Awk Paragraph Formatting Solution

Tags: text, awk, sed

I need to create paragraphs from run-together text from which, for the most part, carriage returns and/or line feeds have been removed. Dialogue is interspersed with the text. So what I'd like is for a blank line to be inserted after the second occurrence of a quote. It looks like the quotes will set off the reconstructed paragaphs. I've added forward slashes (which are not in the text) because I don't know the convention for quoting code on this site. Here's an example:

To go from this:

Bacon ipsum dolor amet pastrami chuck venison swine, salami prosciutto shank            pork belly. Filet mignon beef ribs ham hock, bacon ground round porchetta alcatra. Beef bacon biltong bresaola short loin filet mignon "I want bacon." chuck brisket landjaeger jerky prosciutto ham leberkas pork loin doner. Shoulder tongue meatball tail jerky pork loin filet "I want bacon." mignon shank chuck shankle flank pig. Short loin pork loin hamburger corned beef ribeye tri-tip doner ham hock landjaeger t-bone swine. Swine pork belly frankfurter, t-bone ham hock bacon pastrami. Biltong beef chuck ham hock pork loin shoulder strip "I want bacon."steak short loin tail cupim rump alcatra.Shoulder beef cupim rump ground round. Beef sirloin cupim meatball ham ribeye. "I want bacon." Venison tail ribeye, pastrami tongue pig beef ribs kielbasa bresaola doner. Shankle filet mignon pig, shoulder ball tip pork belly jowl sausage fatback boudin. Prosciutto venison capicola bacon, short loin andouille salami shank tongue corned beef. Sirloin biltong boudin tenderloin brisket tri-tip pancetta kielbasa strip steak leberkas short ribs flank filet mignon ham hock pork. Tri-tip cupim "I want bacon." "I want bacon."

to this:

Bacon ipsum dolor amet pastrami chuck venison swine, salami prosciutto shank pork belly. Filet mignon beef ribs ham hock, bacon ground round porchetta alcatra. Beef bacon biltong bresaola short loin filet mignon

"I want bacon."

chuck brisket landjaeger jerky prosciutto ham leberkas pork loin doner. Shoulder tongue meatball tail jerky pork loin filet

"I want bacon."

mignon shank chuck shankle flank pig. Short loin pork loin hamburger corned beef ribeye tri-tip doner ham hock landjaeger t-bone swine. Swine pork belly frankfurter, t-bone ham hock bacon pastrami. Biltong beef chuck ham hock pork loin shoulder strip

"I want bacon."

steak short loin tail cupim rump alcatra. Shoulder beef cupim rump ground round. Beef sirloin cupim meatball ham ribeye.

"I want bacon."

Venison tail ribeye, pastrami tongue pig beef ribs kielbasa bresaola doner. Shankle filet mignon pig, shoulder ball tip pork belly jowl sausage fatback boudin. Prosciutto venison capicola bacon, short loin andouille salami shank tongue corned beef. Sirloin biltong boudin tenderloin brisket tri-tip pancetta kielbasa strip steak leberkas short ribs flank filet mignon ham hock pork. Tri-tip cupim

"I want bacon."

"I want bacon."

Comment: why are the last two quotations not on separate lines?

Comment: Fixed, the text in the input box was on separate lines but an additional carriage return was needed for the output box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -v RS='"' '{
if (NR % 2 == 1) {
    if (/[^[:space:]]/) printf "%s%s\n\n", (NR==1? "" : "\n"), $0
} else {
    printf "\"%s\"\n", $0
}}' file
```

outputs

```
Bacon ipsum dolor amet pastrami chuck venison swine, salami prosciutto shank pork belly. Filet mignon beef ribs ham hock, bacon ground round porchetta alcatra. Beef bacon biltong bresaola short loin filet mignon 

"I want bacon."

 chuck brisket landjaeger jerky prosciutto ham leberkas pork loin doner. Shoulder tongue meatball tail jerky pork loin filet 

"I want bacon."

 mignon shank chuck shankle flank pig. Short loin pork loin hamburger corned beef ribeye tri-tip doner ham hock landjaeger t-bone swine. Swine pork belly frankfurter, t-bone ham hock bacon pastrami. Biltong beef chuck ham hock pork loin shoulder strip 

"I want bacon."

steak short loin tail cupim rump alcatra.Shoulder beef cupim rump ground round. Beef sirloin cupim meatball ham ribeye. 

"I want bacon."

 Venison tail ribeye, pastrami tongue pig beef ribs kielbasa bresaola doner. Shankle filet mignon pig, shoulder ball tip pork belly jowl sausage fatback boudin. Prosciutto venison capicola bacon, short loin andouille salami shank tongue corned beef. Sirloin biltong boudin tenderloin brisket tri-tip pancetta kielbasa strip steak leberkas short ribs flank filet mignon ham hock pork. Tri-tip cupim 

"I want bacon."
"I want bacon."
```

Comment: Nice! Just a little remark: "Odd" paragraphs start with a blank space (except for the first)

Comment: and there's no blank line between the last 2 "I want bacon." lines.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="\ ?\"\ ?"; ORS="\n\n"}
     NR%2==0{print "\""$0"\"";next;}
     {}1' inputFile
```

This will insert a new paragraph before and after each quotation (`"..."`). However, this will make the last paragraphs look like this

```
"I want bacon."



"I want bacon."
```

To remove the blank paragraph between "I want bacon":

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="\ ?\"\ ?"; ORS="\n\n"}
     NR%2==0{print "\""$0"\"";next;}
     ($0!=""){print $0}' inputFile
```

Comment: This doesn't add a blank line before and after the dialog, but it does print the dialogs on separate lines. The problem now is that without the blank lines the dialogs won't be treated as separate paragraphs.

Comment: Oh, I missed that requirement. I have corrected my answer - I just had to replace `ORS="\n"` by `ORS="\n\n"`. Now, each quotation is preceded and followed by a line break and an empty line.

Comment: Got this: awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
 BEGIN{RS="\ ?\"\ ?" >>>  ORS= <<< "\n\n"} NR%2==0{print "\""$0"\"";next;}{}1
awk: illegal statement at source line 1

Comment: Sorry, `;` was missing after `RS="\ ?\"\ ?"`

Answer (score 0):

sed might be easier

```
$ sed 's/"[^"]*" /\n\n&\n\n/g' bacon
```

example:

```
$ echo "bla bla bla \"This is bacon.\" Starts a new paragraph" | sed 's/"[^"]*" /\n\n&\n\n/g'
bla bla bla

"This is bacon."

Starts a new paragraph
```

Comment: This didn't work. The file was untouched, both running it through sed as well as piping it to another file (>test.txt).

Comment: it will write to stdout.  I added an example.  Perhaps you're using a non compliant `sed`.  Can you check `sed --version`?

Comment: `\n` in a sed script produces undefined behavior per POSIX so maybe that's the issue?

Comment: If you're using a shell (e.g. bash) that allows `$'\n'` for a newline, then consider using `"\\\n"` for each desired newline.

Comment: @Ed Morton, perhaps, I don't have one to test but `sed --posix ..` also worked for me.

Comment: POSIX states the meaning of `\n` is undefined and so any sed can do whatever it likes when it sees that construct and it is still POSIX compliant in that regard. A sed implementer could choose to remove every file in your $HOME when their sed sees `\n` and that sed would still be POSIX compliant, it just wouldn't do what you expect/want. The portable, robust way to use a newline in sed is a backslash followed by a literal newline.

Answer (score 0):

WithGNU awk for multi-char RS and gensub():

```
$ awk -v RS='^$' -v ORS= '{$0=gensub(/\s*("[^"]+")\s*/,"\n\n\\1\n\n","g"); gsub(/\n+/,"\n\n")}1' file
Bacon ipsum dolor amet pastrami chuck venison swine, salami prosciutto shank pork belly. Filet mignon beef ribs ham hock, bacon ground round porchetta alcatra. Beef bacon biltong bresaola short loin filet mignon

"I want bacon."

chuck brisket landjaeger jerky prosciutto ham leberkas pork loin doner. Shoulder tongue meatball tail jerky pork loin filet

"I want bacon."

mignon shank chuck shankle flank pig. Short loin pork loin hamburger corned beef ribeye tri-tip doner ham hock landjaeger t-bone swine. Swine pork belly frankfurter, t-bone ham hock bacon pastrami. Biltong beef chuck ham hock pork loin shoulder strip

"I want bacon."

steak short loin tail cupim rump alcatra.Shoulder beef cupim rump ground round. Beef sirloin cupim meatball ham ribeye.

"I want bacon."

Venison tail ribeye, pastrami tongue pig beef ribs kielbasa bresaola doner. Shankle filet mignon pig, shoulder ball tip pork belly jowl sausage fatback boudin. Prosciutto venison capicola bacon, short loin andouille salami shank tongue corned beef. Sirloin biltong boudin tenderloin brisket tri-tip pancetta kielbasa strip steak leberkas short ribs flank filet mignon ham hock pork. Tri-tip cupim

"I want bacon."

"I want bacon."
```